# LINQ find all child entities meet requirements

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have a table Request and a table Task. Request to Task is one to many relationship. In Request there is a status. There's also a status in Task. Sometimes people mark all Tasks status complete but not marking Request's status as complete. I need to do some maintenance work on it. Here is my code:

```
List<Request> RequestsNeedsAction = new List<Request>();
var requests = Requests.Where(r => r.RequestStatusID == 2 || 
                                   r.RequestStatusID == 6)
                       .ToList();

foreach (var request in requests)
{
    bool taskAllCompleted = true;
    foreach (var task in request.Tasks)
    {
        if (task.TaskStatusID != 2 && task.TaskStatusID != 5)
        {
            taskAllCompleted = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( taskAllCompleted )
    {
        RequestsNeedsAction.Add( request );
    }   
}

RequestsNeedsAction.Dump();
```

Is there an easier way to do this in LINQ or in tsql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var RequestsNeedsAction = Requests.Where(r => 
    (r.RequestStatusID == 2 || r.RequestStatusID == 6) 
    && !r.Tasks.Any( t => t.TaskStatusID != 2 && t.TaskStatusID != 5)).ToList();
```

Comment: I want to use just one query to get all requests that has all the completed tasks, If I change Any to Where, I get all the tasks. However, I just want Requests, How do I do that?

Comment: @Meidi revisiting my answer, I realized that was completely wrong. That you want is the updated one. Please let me know if that's ok now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just need to put an negative before that r.Tasks.Any... then I get all the completed ones. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have an additional question. In Task table there's a column called UpdatedDate, so In addition to these Requests, I want to get the latest UpdatedDate Task along with the Requst. How do I approach this?

Comment: Could you please post another question for this and make more clear with an example what you have and what you want to get? Just share the link of the new question. Thanks

Comment: Solved by doing this: from r in Requests
    .Where(r => 
        (r.RequestStatusID == 2 || r.RequestStatusID == 6) && 
        r.Tasks.All(t => t.TaskStatusID == 2 || t.TaskStatusID == 5))
let maxTask = r.Tasks.Where (t => t.UpdatedOn == r.Tasks.Max (ta => ta.UpdatedOn)).FirstOrDefault()
join u in Users on maxTask.AssignedEmp equals u.UserID
orderby r.RequestID descending
select new
{
 r.RequestID,
 maxTask.TaskID,
 LastUpdatedDate = maxTask.UpdatedOn,
 u.FirstName,
 u.LastName,
 u.Email
}

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.  You do not say in the question but I am inferring from the code that a request is not complete if the `RequestStatusId` is 2 or 6 and a task is complete if the `TaskStatusId` is 2 or 5.

```
List<Request> RequestsNeedsAction =
    Requests
    .Where(r => 
        (r.RequestStatusID == 2 || r.RequestStatusID == 6) && 
        r.Tasks.All(t => task.TaskStatusID == 2 || task.TaskStatusID == 5))
    .ToList();
```